# Check from Apex whether user has verified their email

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I am currently using the `System.UserManagement.sendAsyncEmailConfirmation` method to send a verification email to new community users when they sign up. I can create a view from the Users page in setup that shows me the checkbox for `User Verified Email`. How can I access this field (`User Verified Email`) in my Apex code?

For more context, I want to send the AsyncEmailConfirmation before a new user user can create a password and log in to the community. So, I need to check if the user's email has been verified from the controller of my Visual Force change password page before I let them create a password. Is there an alternative way I can accomplish this process?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_async_email_verification.htm&type=5 I think you can actually access verification-specific fields as you should be able to create a new list view based on this.

I have not implemented it but I found that we were able to create a new list view using those fields so thought to convey the details.

Comment: This is not the problem that I am having. I know I can create the view with the field, but I need to access the field from my apex code.